# Piping with stdout in Python threads

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, multithreading, pipe

I'm trying to modify some data recieved through a socket for a parser, and later sends the result to stdout, while also looping infinitely on a interval to send more output. I've assumed the best way to do this is with threading. When I test the module in a terminal everything is printed the way it should, but not when the stdout of the module is piped to another process using a bash script. The module is not updating on the regular interval or when the data is sent through the parser. It occasionally randomly updates and I'm not sure why.

This all seams to be solved when I use `subprocess.run(['echo', '-e', result])` instead of `print`, and I'm wondering why this is happening, and the correct way to pipe to stdout from seperate threads in Python. My OS is Debian 10.

Comment: Tried running Python with `-u` (unbuffered streams)? See https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u

Comment: Or explicitly `flush()` the streams when you want the bytes to go to the downstream process.